# Consider removing the alias [parse]

Tags: discussion, retag-request

[parse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse) is currently an alias for [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing). However, it appears to be common to assume that it means [parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse.com), which is commonly referred to as "Parse".

There is probably a good reason why the word "Parse" was chosen for a database in the cloud service, but it isn't apparent to me. The pollution of the [parsing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parsing) tag is.

I don't know if removing the alias is the correct solution. But it would be nice if some action could be taken, other than daily tag edits.

Comment: So, [parse] shall be completely abandoned and kept destroyed? Well, that might work, but I guess someone will have to keep an eye on it to *keep* it destroyed. BTW: Since mid-2010 the synonym triggered 6k times. Compare that with currently 28.5k questions in the tag... and 8.6K in [parse.com].

Comment: @deduplicator: It would be interesting to know how many of the triggers in the last year were correct. (Perhaps correct means that the parsing tag wasn't removed by an edit.)

Comment: Yes. But I guess that is a question for a community manager or even a dev, because I don't think that information is offered by default to anyone. Might make a good feature-request asking for getting that added to the synonym info pages...

Comment: @Deduplicator: As a sample point, in the slightly more than four hours since I posted this proposal, there were four posts to [tag:parsing] of which three (75%) should have been (and are now) tagged [tag:parse.com]