# Should we make tag [parse.com] a synonym of [parse-server]?

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags, synonym-request

### Issue

Questions related to Parse Server are today tagged with [parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse.com) which is the deprecated URL of the retired Parse service (that leads into no-where now), before its release as Parse Server as open source on parseplatform.org.

Because the [parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse.com) tag has been around longer (18,928 questions tagged) than [parse-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-server) (1,254 questions tagged), it is still commonly used for discoverability.

However "parse.com" is neither a valid URL nor a product name, nor a technology. So it doesn't make sense to keep using it. "Parse Server" however is the official name of the open source project.

The two tags cannot be used interchangeably, because while Parse was a commercial product the questions were mostly related to the SDK and then existing commercial API limitations, while now many limitations are lifted and questions are also related to the setup of the open source server.

### Discussion

What is considered best practice in this case to prevent users from using a tag that isn't applicable anymore?

Comment: "What is considered best practice in this case to prevent users from using a tag that isn't applicable anymore?" Remove the tag of the system. If that doesn't work, blacklist.

Comment: When the tag is removed or blacklisted, are the currently tagged questions still tagged, or will it disappear all together from SO?

Comment: If it was removed from the system, how can there be questions tagged with it?

Comment: Depends on the definition of "remove" in this context.

Comment: SO askers use tags to find experts.  Current ones are Jake, flovilmart, Kashif, Julian.  They respond both to [parse.com] and [parse-server] tag.  This is normal, SO contributors don't stop being experts just because a company gives up on a product.  So not a problem at all, a "best practice" is to do nothing.  If you have to edit the tag then make sure you only do so on the questions that matter.  So these experts don't get too much crap reactivated on their Interesting page.

Comment: @HansPassant A tag should also be meaningful. [Parse.com] is the deprecated marketing URL of a discontinued service. SO reads, `A tag is a word or phrase that describes the topic of the question.` All questions today are related to [parse-server], not the discontinued commercial [parse.com] product with partly different characteristics (commercial API limitations, etc). For someone who doesn't know the history of Parse Server, the tag is confusing. It is also used wrongly, because questions for setting up the server have nothing to do with the commercial [parse.com] service.

Comment: Another option of course is to just wait until the [parse.com] tag is not used anymore and the problem will solve by itself. It seems that it is used less and less over time and people will eventually stop to double-tag because they won't know what [parse.com] is (also, because is pointing to an "invalid" URL).

Comment: I added the [parse-server] tag a few years ago when Parse.com was shutting down and the open source version was becoming a common replacement. The [parse.com] tag was supposed to be for questions related to the now shutdown website/webservice. The newer [parse-server] tag should be used for question related to using your own Parse server. Making one a synonym of the other seems wrong.

Comment: @rmaddy: If that's the case, then the tag info for [tag:parse.com] ought to be edited to make it clear that the tag should not be used for new questions. Anyway, I'll start retagging [tag:parsing] questions as [tag:parse-server] instead of [tag:parse.com]

Comment: OK, I edited the tag info excerpt. Also, I think it would be cool if [tag:parse] wasn't a synonym for anything, in order to avoid questions which should be about [tag:parse-server] ending up in [tag:parsing]. (I've requested that before but I recognize it is not a high-priority request.)

Comment: Regarding the [parsing] tag - It specifically states that it should not be used for questions related to Parse yet people do it all of the time.

Comment: @rmaddy: Yes, I know. But I think some of the time that's because people type "parse", thinking that is what they are asking about (and, of course, it is). And then that gets automatically changed to [tag:parsing] because it's a synonym. Which is why I think the synonym should be deleted.

Comment: For reference: request to delete alias, about three years ago: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/289076/consider-removing-the-alias-parse

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/381447/rename-tag-parse-com-to-parse-platform [status-declined] as the parse community decided to go in a different route

Comment: @BhargavRao, @Arthur-Cinader is the lead at parse now - and requests that we don't need `parse-server` either, so could we consolidate this into `parse-platform` too, please?

Comment: The product is known as “parse server”, rather than “parse platform”. While “parse platform” may be a technically correct umbrella term, I am unsure about it’s practical usage. Compare google hits for both terms.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ideally, we would rename both parse-server and parse.com to parse-platform.

EDIT: 
Based on a [separate conversation](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5419) on the parse-server issues (irony not missed) I'm now convinced that you were right and we should not combine the two tags.

Comment: While I find this a good idea, the product is called „parse server“ and there would be no tag for it on SO anymore. I am not 100% convinced of this answer.

Comment: A part of the product is parse-server.  There's also a half dozen SDKs, a half dozen adapters, cloud code, and the documentation.  The domain is 'parseplatform'. We want to get behind that.  The volume of questions doesn't merits breaking all of this out under different tags. The hope is that users would use multiple tags like 'parse-platform', 'iOS' to help categorize.  We want to focus all power on a single tag.  We're changing our documentation to point to SO as the question asking place for the Parse Platform so we want a focused place to link to.

Comment: You have a point, however `parse server` is the by far most used term to reference the whole platform as of today - because it is the central product around which all other sub-products revolve. It took a while for people to start transitioning from `parse.com` to `parse server` tag. I see two possible approaches: a) try to change user behavior with yet another transition to the uncommon term `parse platform` or b) rebrand the platform around its central product `parse server`. Google terms: https://trends.google.com/trends/explore?date=today%205-y&geo=US&q=parse%20platform,parse%20server

Comment: @Manuel I sympathetic to your point.  The Parse Platform decision is one that has been made in a number of ways (documentation, domain) and changing that now is outside of the scope of what we can accomplish with our limited, volunteer resources. or at least it is not a current priority.  In all seriousness, if you'd like to undertake to rationalize it, I'm super open to that. Otherwise, I am just trying to follow through on a path that has already been started a year or so ago. I believe we should combine our Stack Overflow into a single tag one way or another to best serve our users.

Comment: I think that most people who are familiar with the project (I.e use it on a regular basis) are accustomed to the name Parse Platform and newcomers are likely to notice quickly given that the top result for the search “Parse Server” is the Parse Platform website (on both DuckDuckGo and Google).

Comment: Sounds reasonable, so ‚parse platform‘ it is 

Comment: uh, can do I 180.? Based on a [separate conversation](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5419) on the parse-server issues (irony not missed) I'm now convinced that you were right and we should not combine the two tags.