# Rename tag [parse.com] to [parse-platform]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, retag-request

We the [parse community](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5419#issuecomment-473966186) would like to rename the tag [parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse.com) as it's still actively being used, but technically incorrect.

The new name of this tag will be [parse-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-platform)

I notice that you've [discussed this before](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/364789/should-we-make-tag-parse-com-a-synonym-of-parse-server) and have determined that the tag will effectively transition to [parse-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-server) organically, however, this is not happening. I believe this is because [parse-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-server) is a very narrow topic in relation to the products we have to offer.

It is, therefore, requested that we keep [parse-server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-server) for questions specifically related to the node.js server. And all other queries IE. SDKs, dashboard, general platform help, set up, hosting eg. be tagged using the newly renamed [parse-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-platform).

Comment: The reason it isn't happening is because retag efforts do require a decent number of people to get involved for it to happen with any pace, and ideally we'd land a few experts in the technologies to be sure what we were doing was sane.

Comment: @Makoto This request is the result of a discussion from both longstanding and new contributors of the Parse Platform - [here](https://github.com/parse-community/parse-server/issues/5419).

Comment: @Makoto Can't a moderator (or employee) just rename the tag?

Comment: @Bergi: Maybe, but I know a community owner can, without touching the questions.

Comment: @Bergi Yes, mods can merge the tag into a non-existent tag, effectively renaming it without modifying any questions.

Comment: Note that questions about "hosting" and "general platform help" will likely be off topic on Stack Overflow. See [Can I support my product on this site?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/product-support) and the FAQ [How can I use Stack Overflow to support our developer community?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326374/215552).

Comment: @HereticMonkey - thanks to good to know, we have a discourse set up too, so that would be a better area for those questions, we'll make sure to update the FAQs.

Answer (score 4):

As Makoto has already mentioned, rename and retag efforts are hard. We've been trying to talk to experts in a given tag before doing any of these. I get it that it is trivial to change the name, and even if it was done inaccurately it is fairly easy to revert it back, however, it would cause a lot of disruption in the tag users' day to day activity.

Given that the entire community of parse.com is happy with this change, and needs it, I have renamed the tag from [parse.com](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse.com) to [parse-platform](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/parse-platform). The 19,116 questions
 associated with the former tag is now associated with the newer tag.

Comment: "it would cause a lot of disruption in the tag users' day to day activity" please elaborate. How so?

Comment: There might be a lot of users who have subscribed to the tag, through feeds, API, etc. Making a mistake in renaming tags prematurely would just send them off into a disarray. It isn't that renaming now makes it less disruptive, just that if the top users are aware of it, then it probably makes sense.

Comment: The system remaps subscription automagically, so that's not a concern. Feeds and api request aren't remaped, but those are usually solved with synonyms. I really don't know why in this particular case you are so conservative, when usually my complains are that those tools are used too lightly.

Comment: For remapping, we need to do merges, which are permanent. A wrong merge is irreversible, even on the CM side. Synonyms don't usually help you remap the older ones, at least on the API side. Also, funny that you inform that I've been conservative... In the past year, the number of open tag issue requests have reduced half way. It is not that I'm conservative, I would like to make sure that whatever action I take is accurate.

Comment: "I really don't know why **in this particular case** you are so conservative" please, be accurate. Renaming tags via merging tags is easy to undo, you just need to merge to the previous name tag.

Comment: I also mentioned that it is trivial to rename tags, and undo them, in the very paragraph.